# One to many relationship , data not getting seeded in database

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I got this code from where it was working properly. The Department class and ApplicationUser class  has one to many relationship. I am trying to seed data. The roles are being added to the database , but not the user or the department.
This is the ApplicationUser class

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {

        //n-1 relationship
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required, MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
```

This is the department class

```
public class Department : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Employees { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the Context class

```
 public class ManageContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole<int>,int>
    {
        public ManageContext(DbContextOptions<ManageContext> dbContextOptions) :base(dbContextOptions)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

        //the name of the table will be same as the name of the class
        private static void SetTableNamesAsSingle(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Use the entity name instead of the Context.DbSet<T> name
            foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).ToTable(entityType.ClrType.Name);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            SetTableNamesAsSingle(builder);

            base.OnModelCreating(builder); 

        }
    }
```

There are 2 separate classes to seed the data. These have static methods in them to seed and create roles and users.
This is the dataseeder class which is being used to seed the department class

```
public class DataSeeder
    {
        public static async Task SeedAsync(ManageContext manageContext, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, int? retry = 0)
        {
            int retryForAvailability = retry.Value;

            try
            {
                await SeedDepartmentAsync(manageContext);
                
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (retryForAvailability < 10)
                {
                    retryForAvailability++;
                    var log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ManageContext>();
                    log.LogError(exception.Message);
                    await SeedAsync
                        (manageContext, loggerFactory, retryForAvailability);
                }
                throw;
            }
        }


        private static async Task SeedDepartmentAsync(ManageContext manageContext)
        {

            if (manageContext.Departments.Any())
                return;

            var department = new List<Department>()
            {
                new Department() { Name ="HR"},
                new Department() { Name = "IT"}
            };


            manageContext.Departments.AddRange(department);
            await manageContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
 }
```

This the identityseeder class which is creating the roles and the user and populating the database

```
  public class IdentitySeeder
    {
      
        #region Public Methods
        public static void Seed(
           ManageContext manageContext,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
            )
        {
            // Create default Users (if there are none)
            if (!manageContext.Users.Any())
            {
                CreateUsers(manageContext, roleManager, userManager)
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Seed Methods
        private static async Task CreateUsers(
            ManageContext manageContext,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            // local variables
            DateTime createdDate = new DateTime(2021, 03, 17, 12, 30, 00);
            DateTime lastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

            string role_Administrator = "Administrator";
            string role_RegisteredUser = "RegisteredUser";

            //Create Roles (if they doesn't exist yet)
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role_Administrator))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(role_Administrator));
            }
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role_RegisteredUser))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(role_RegisteredUser));
            }

            // Create the "Admin" ApplicationUser account
         
            var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                FirstName = "Breta",
                LastName = "Collins",
                Role = "Administrator",
                Email = "bretacollins@mail.com",
                UserName = "breta.collins",
              

            };
            // Insert "Admin" into the Database and assign the "Administrator" and "Registered" roles to him.
          
            if (await userManager.FindByIdAsync(user_Admin.Id.ToString()) == null)
            {
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, "Password1!");
               
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin, role_Administrator);

               
                // Remove Lockout and E-Mail confirmation.
                user_Admin.EmailConfirmed = true;
                user_Admin.LockoutEnabled = false;



            }

            await manageContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the Program class

```
 public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            SeedDatabase(host);

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

        private static void SeedDatabase(IWebHost host)
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

                try
                {
                    var manageContext = services.GetRequiredService<ManageContext>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    IdentitySeeder.Seed(manageContext ,roleManager ,userManager);

                   
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                    logger.LogError(exception, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am new to it and making this as my learning project. The error that I am getting is
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUsers_Department_DepartmentId". The conflict occurred in database "ManageDatabase", table "dbo.Department", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated."
I am not sure how to solve this error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to seed  Department table before seeding ApplicationUser. Since DepartmentId is not nullable , you have to assign DepartmentId to your new ApplicationUser instance:

```
var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                FirstName = "Breta",
                LastName = "Collins",
                Role = "Administrator",
                Email = "bretacollins@mail.com",
                UserName = "breta.collins",
                DepartmentId=1 //or what you need

            };
```

or you can change DepartmentId type

```
  public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
```

but in this case a DepartmentId column of your Db table should be null too.

Comment: I had tried it, but it gives me the same error.  Could it be possible because the Department data is not getting seeded into the database?

Comment: Hi I was able to get it working by changing  DepartmentId to null as you said and calling the DataSeeder class in the program class. Thank you for your help

Comment: If  you changed DepartmentId to null,  assigning DepartmentId to ApplicationUser is optional. Only if you need.